# Visual Studio 2005 throws build error in soapclient.cpp I built with GSoap

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, gsoap

I have built soapclient.cpp using GSoap libraries all built successfully, without any errors. Now included the necessary files to the project as instructed by the guide (http://www.genivia.com/dev.html#Example_gSOAP_client_(C++)), but getting following errors, included some here. has anyone come across it, any ideas?

i am using gSoap release 2.8.27

Includes:

```
soapH.h
soapStub.h
soapSubscribeNetBindingProxy.h
stdsoap2.h
SubscribeNetBinding.nsmap
soapC.cpp, soapClient.cpp, and stdsoap2.cpp

Errors---
Error      1              error C2079: 'soap_tmp_ns__echoString' uses     undefined struct 'soap_call_ns__echoString::ns__echoString'                c:\dev\riedel\riedellicencemanager\riedellicencemanager\subscribenetproxy\soapclient.cpp   23          
Error      2              error C2228: left of '.inputString' must have class/struct/union                c:\dev\riedel\riedellicencemanager\riedellicencemanager\subscribenetproxy\soapclient.cpp   27          
Error      3              error C3861: 'soap_serialize_ns__echoString': identifier not found                c:\dev\riedel\riedellicencemanager\riedellicencemanager\subscribenetproxy\soapclient.cpp   29          
Error      4              error C3861: 'soap_put_ns__echoString': identifier not found                c:\dev\riedel\riedellicencemanager\riedellicencemanager\subscribenetproxy\soapclient.cpp   36          
Error      5              error C3861: 'soap_put_ns__echoString': identifier not found                c:\dev\riedel\riedellicencemanager\riedellicencemanager\subscribenetproxy\soapclient.cpp   47          
Error      6              error C3861: 'soap_get_ns__echoStringResponse': identifier not found                c:\dev\riedel\riedellicencemanager\riedellicencemanager\subscribenetproxy\soapclient.cpp   60          
Error      7              error C2027: use of undefined type 'soap_call_ns__echoString::ns__echoStringResponse'                c:\dev\riedel\riedellicencemanager\riedellicencemanager\subscribenetproxy\soapclient.cpp   67          
Error      8              error C2227: left of '->_return' must point to class/struct/union/generic type                c:\dev\riedel\riedellicencemanager\riedellicencemanager\subscribenetproxy\soapclient.cpp   67          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following.
Remove any references to stdafx.h, from the project
Remove soapClient.cpp
Make sure each cpp file included is to 'Not using pre-compiled headers'
Include dom.h
Include dom.cpp

Project should compile now. if need further help start from calc_vs2005 project included in the gSoap.